# Can Google's Speech API accept an external Video URL?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I recently figured out that Google's Vision API can accept an external image URL and I was curious if anyone knew if Google's Speech could accept an external video URL such as a YouTube video?

The code I have in my mind would look something like this:

```
def transcribe_gcs(yotube_url):
    """Asynchronously transcribes the audio file specified by the gcs_uri."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=youtube_url)  # swapped out gcs_uri with youtube_url
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
#         sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US')

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    response = operation.result(timeout=90)

    # Each result is for a consecutive portion of the audio. Iterate through
    # them to get the transcripts for the entire audio file.
    for result in response.results:
        # The first alternative is the most likely one for this portion.
        print(u'Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
```

Answer (score 0):

> I was curious if anyone knew if Google's Speech could accept an
>   external video URL such as a YouTube video?

It needs to be a local path to your audio file (less than 1 min audio file) or GCS URI for audio file longer than [1 minute](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas#content). What you're thinking is not possible, the audio/video file needs to be in GCS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by streaming same video (for example on wowza or on any server of your choice.) and then simply extract audio using lets say ffmpeg and pass this to google. It should work. use StreamingRecognizeRequest instead of RecognitionAudio.